# S3 Lambda Trigger not triggering for EVERY file upload

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-lambda

In Python Django, I save multiple video files.

Save 1:

- Long Video
- Short Video

Save 2:

- Long Video
- Short Video

Save 3:

- Long Video
- Short Video

I have a lambda trigger that uses media converter to add HLS formats to these videos as well as generate thumbnails. These 3 saves are done in very short time periods between each other since they are assets to a Social Media Post object.

For some reason the S3 triggers for only some of the files.

Save 1 triggers S3 Lambda but not Save 2.
Save 3 also triggers S3 Lambda.

My assumption is that the S3 trigger has some sort of downtime in between identifying new file uploads (In which case, I think the period in between these file uploads are near instant).

Is this assumption correct and how can I circumvent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should fire for *all* objects.

When Amazon S3 triggers an AWS Lambda function, information about the object that caused the trigger is passed in the `events` field:

```json
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "s3": {
        "bucket": {
          "name": "my-s3-bucket",
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "HappyFace.jpg",
          "size": 1024,
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that **this is an array**, so it is **possible that multiple objects could be passed** to one Lambda function. I have never definitively seen this happen, but the sample code from AWS certainly assumes this can happen based on their sample code:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  for record in event['Records']:   # <-- Looping here
      bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
      key = unquote_plus(record['s3']['object']['key'])
      ...
```

Therefore, I would recommend:

- Print the `event` at the start of the function to put it into the log for later examination
- Use a loop to go through all records that might be passed
- Let us know what you found!

Comment: You're awesome! There was indeed multiple files being sent to the lambda at once and I had to iterate through each record. I should have dived deeper into the Lambda Documentations for this one. Thanks!